# Can I have two instances of Fancybox 2.0?

Tags: fancybox

I have Fancybox 2.0 installed on my site, modified slightlyto look like the Facebook image preview box. I want to have a second "instance" of Fancybox, but for it to be positioned differently. My image preview Fancybox (the current instance) should be 20px from the top (as it is at the moment), but my share dialog Fancybox (the second instance) should be 450px by 300px (dimensions for example purposes only, I have not looked at it in depth) and positioned in the centre of the page (as Fancybox defaults to). Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can...
I did it on my web site..

first fancybox ues..

```
.fancybox-wrap {
margin: Xpx 0 0 Ypx;
}
```

to position you box..

to dynamically set the position...
you need to do two things...
A:  add a javascript before document.ready() fuunction
B: add a onclick in you hyperlink...

so when somebody click the link ,it will change the css before fancybox appear..

the java script as follow (I get from the web, it is a function to dynamically change CSS value)

```
    function css(selector, property, value) {
for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length;i++) {//Loop through all styles
//Try add rule
try { document.styleSheets[i].insertRule(selector+ ' {'+property+':'+value+'}',
document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length);
} catch(err) {try { document.styleSheets[i].addRule(selector, property+':'+value);} catch(err)
{}}//IE
}
}
```

the hyper link example:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="showmybox.html"  onclick="css('.fancybox-
wrap', 'margin', '-100px 0 0 250px')">
```

(this will show you box at up-right corner)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to have two instances of fancybox "**at the same time**" by default (version 2 and previous). If you are good at jQuery you may try to modify the original script (but it would be like re-inventing the wheel).

The only modal box I have seen doing that is jQuery Tools Overlay - http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/multiple.html