# How do I open a fancybox window from another one (parent), and how do I keep parent window after open the second one?

Tags: jqgrid, fancybox

I am using fancybox on my web project, and I need to open a fancybox window from another one, already opened. But this aproach is giving some problems, beacause when the second window open, it opens his content in the same window of the first one.

I wanted to know how can I open the second window from it's parent, but keeping the first one opened, so the users from my application could use the first window, after closing the second window.

Answer (score 0):

Opening two instances of fancybox at the same time is not possible [Check this answered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773018/1055987).

However, you may open a fancybox window inside another one. The only way to do this is to create a separated functional child page with its specific fancybox scripts and links and then open this (child) page from another one using the `type` option set to `iframe`. Be sure that the parent fancybox is big enough to contain the child box.