# Trying to open a fancybox from another but without closing the first?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

Im using fancybox to show some content, and it is working fine.

But I also have inside my fancybox content, some links  to open others fancyboxs that will show pdf´s.

And it is working fine, but When I close my last fancybx opened, I also close my first fancybox opened.

So, I came here to ask you, if it is possible, open a fancybox from another, but when you close the last opened fancybox, I want to go back to the first fancybox and not want them to be both closed, wich is what Im getting now.

I have this html:

```
<article class="loop-news">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <span>Date of today</span>
  <p>content of my article</p>
  <a class="fancybox" href="#show">Read more</a>

//then I have my div that will appear inside fancybox when click on "read more"

  <div class="fancybox-container">
    <div id="show">
      echo <h2>Title</h2>
      <span>Date of today</span>
      <p>content of my news</p>
//here I have some pdfs inside fancybox, that will open other fancybox
    <div  class="pdfs">
      <li><a class="fancybox_pdf" href="pdf1.pdf">Title of pdf</a></li>
      <li><a class="fancybox_pdf" href="pdf1.pdf">Title of pdf</a></li>
   </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

This is my fancybox script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '80%',
        height      : '80%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',    
    });
})
```

This is my fancybox script to open pdf:

```
    $(".fancybox_pdf").fancybox({
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
    autoSize: false,
        type: 'iframe',
        iframe: {
          preload: false
        }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772272/can-i-have-two-instances-of-fancybox-2-0

Comment: Thanks for your awnser. So it looks like it is not possible. Do you know some fancybox alternative that allows what I´m trying?

Comment: http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/multiple.html

Comment: Thanks JFK, I will try with that plugin. But do you know also, if with jquery ui dialogs, it is possible open a fancybox inside a opened dialog box?

Comment: JFK, I was here finding a solution for my problem, as I had everything working with fancybox, I liked to continue with fancybox. So I was thinking, for example, it is possible when I close the second fancybox, do something that allow previous fancybox open automatically?

Comment: I see there is the `onClosed` event in the http://fancybox.net/api which you cold in theory use to open the "previous" one once the 2nd once gets closed.  Be sure to make the close/open animations for that transition as short/non-existent as possible to give more of an impression that the first one was there all the time.